# Populating ListGridFields in smartgwt

Tags: smartgwt

This is my code snippet:

```
    final ListGrid subscriberGrid = new ListGrid();
    subscriberGrid.setWidth(500);
    subscriberGrid.setHeight(224);
    subscriberGrid.setShowAllRecords(true);
    subscriberGrid.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SIMPLE);
    subscriberGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);

    ListGridField fnField = new ListGridField("fn", "First Name");
    ListGridField lnField = new ListGridField("ln", "Last Name");
    ListGridField emailField = new ListGridField("email", "E-mail");
    subscriberGrid.setFields(fnField, lnField, emailField);
```

How do I enter values for it? I tried initiating a ListGridRecord[], but I was unable to fill any values properly. I also tried with a Javascript Object, but that also gave me an error. Googling also did not return satisfactory results.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ahh Darn. I got the answer after asking it.

```
        ListGridRecord temp = new ListGridRecord();

        temp.setAttribute("fn", "foo");
        temp.setAttribute("ln", "bar");
        temp.setAttribute("email", "baz");

        ListGridRecord[] record = { temp };

        subscriberGrid.setData(record);
```

Sorry for the clutter ^-^